# The push notifications does not appear with pop. They appear only minimized

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app, mobilepush-android

I've followed the steps to configure push notifications that I've seen here https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html but the push notifications does not appear with pop, they appear only minimized.

What can be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's already resolved. To be able to see the heads-up notification:

for api < OREO :

- you have set priority high to the builder and set the vibration:

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = 
  NotificationManager.getDefaultNotificationBuilder(context, 
  notificationMessage, NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context),R.drawable.ic_arrow)
                                  .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                  .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

for API >= OREO :

- you have to create a custom channel and pass it the priority, so that:

  NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, 
  "Notifications", android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);